# What is the actual need for IIS in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

*Hey guys I just encountered with a bit of confusion while learning ASP.NET MVC. So, please can you explain in simple terms why need to host web application to web server if, as I learned MVC, controller is there to handle requests and responds, that is, why on earth need IIS while there is controller. Yes, you can say this question is quite stupid but I cannot tell them apart Web server and controller thus I need your help.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: IIS serves your controllers as callable end-points. IIS is a web server. You can read more about MVC life-cycle on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application

About IIS server:[what-is-iis-server](https://www.quora.com/How-does-IIS-SERVER-work)

Long Story;

IIS: this guy hosts your any application. the application can be MVC, ASP web site. It basically runs a process to listen specific port(s) if there is any request on it. So it stands outer of your served application.

Controller: When IIS(with net core you can serve your application via many web-servers (I personally use kestrel)) handle a request and addresses your application, your MVC pipeline kicks in. It handles the request(this request shaped for the application by IIS already) then, execute routes-handlers-filters. Then finally, your controller can process its method.

Comment: Thank you for attention and reply, Yes I have visited the links you provided and all of them explains in scientific way. So, you mean IIS and controller are the same. Please can you explain:)?

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I've detailed the answer. And I tried to keep it short and informative at the same time